# iphone - programmatically rotate system keyboard to landscape when device is in portrait orientation

Tags: iphone

I would like to do this because the keyboard buttons are slightly bigger in landscape mode than portrait and I will have older users using my app.

Does anybody know a way to do it??

Thanks.

Comment: But wait, if your keyboard is landscape then user has to rotate the iphone to be landscape as well. So, why not just force the whole view to be landscape?

Comment: you mean by rotating the view and UITextField? I did that but keyboard still comes up in portrait.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keyboard will show up in the orientation of the statusbar, which doesn't always change with rotations for some reason.  So if you want to display that view only in landscape set `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;` or whichever orientation you want to prefer in your `viewWillAppear` method.